# Detecting errors on Excel Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a simple way to enumerate the errors in a range?

I tried to use the following code, but it does not work

```
Dim err As Object

For Each err In Plan10.Range("M2:AB8000").Errors
    Debug.Print err.Value
Next err
```

I know from the documentation, that I can't simply enumerate errors using the `range.errors`.
I solved the problem scanning every error in every cell in the range, but it is painfully slow

Is there a better way to do the job?

Comment: I dont know if this might help, but I am expecting none or a very little quantity of errors

Comment: You could try putting the error object into a collection? Would that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SpecialCells` to retrieve cells that contain/evaluate to errors

The error handling avoids `VBA` errors if there are no error cells in the range being searched

You can then work through the error ranges (if present in `rng1` and `rng2`) as required

```
Sub GetErrors()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Sheets(1).Range("M2:AB8000").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors)
Set rng2 = Sheets(1).Range("M2:AB8000").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Constant errors at " & rng1.Address
If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Formulae errors at " & rng2.Address
End Sub
```